# gulp with gulp-sequence package fail

Tags: gulp

I try to use gulp and gulp-sequence together, follow the instructions of the npm website, i just try a simple example to test if all the things works. But to my surprise the basic example does not works, someone has a tip about what the problem ?

**node**: v10.15.3

**gulp**: 4.0.1

**gulp-sequence**: 1.0.0

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence')

gulp.task('lint', function (cb) {
  cb()
})

gulp.task('default', gulpSequence('lint'))
```

I expected the simple execution :

```
[12:01:15] Starting 'default'...
[12:01:15] Finished 'default' after 2.56 ms
```

But instead i received the error:

```
TypeError: gulp.on(...).on(...).on(...).on(...).start is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gulp 4, you don't need `gulp-sequence` and can use the built-in `gulp.series` function. This should work:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp')

gulp.task('lint', function (cb) {
  cb()
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('lint'))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!